# App gets stopped when screen orientation changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I am facing an issue wherein the app gets killed when the screen orientation is changed. (Auto rotate is on for the device). My app has fragments as its components. The app stops only when i navigate through different fragments which are linked to each other and not when just the home page is launched. Posting the logcats when the app gets stopped forcibly. Can someone please tell me why it is happening?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.tel.its.its, PID: 17162
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tel.its.its/com.tel.its.its.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4053)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
       at com.tel.its.its.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4053)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.tel.its.its.Fragment_PIS did not create a view.
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2145)
       at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5328)
       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
       at com.tel.its.its.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4053)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Comment: Change error for coding formate

Comment: perhaps in your landscape layout.... some xml problem...See your Xml layout-lanscape if there